# Call a test method twice with same parameter of different datatype

Tags: c#, json, .net, api, specflow

I'm trying to reduce the duplicate code by combining two tests validation methods. Both test methods pass three parameters (actualResponse, expectedReponse, filterParams) but the problem is that even if the two methods have define the same name for parameters their datatype are different.

Here is the summary of the script:

**TestSteps.cs class where these methods are called:**

```
public class TestSteps : BaseTest
{

     // _result holds the actual results coming from context get cal
     private Context _result = new();

     // _SolutionExpectedResponse have expected response from json file.
     private readonly Context _SolutionExpectedResponse = new();

    public TestSteps()
      {
        string jsonstring = File.ReadAllText(@Path of response.json file);
        _SolutionExpectedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Context>(jsonstring);
      }
      [When(@Call context api)]
      public void WhenCallContextAPI()
      {
        _result = Context.GetAsync(token,resource).Result;
      }

      [Then(@Verify the response Values)]
      public void ThenVerifyTheResponseValues()
      {
        ValidateDataValues(_result.Data, _SolutionExpectedResponse.Data, new string[] {"data"})

        ValidateSensitiveDataValues(_result.SensitiveData, _SolutionExpectedResponse.SensitiveData, new string[] {"sensitiveData"})
      }
}
```

**BaseTest.cs class where validate methods were wrote:**

**Method #1:**

```
Protected void ValidateDataValues(List<DataReadable> actualResponse,  List <DataReadable> expectedResponse,  string[] filterParams)

{

  if (filterParams.contains("data"))
  {
    if(actualResponse !=null)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < expectedResponse.Count; i++)
        {
           if((actualResponse[i].Key !=null)
                      {
                actualResponse[i].Key.Value.ToString().Should.BeEquivalentTo(expectedResponse[i].Key.Value.ToString());
              }
        }
        return;
    }
    else
    {
       actualResponse.Should().BeNull();
    }
  }

}
```

**Method #2:**

```
Protected void ValidateSensitiveDataValues(List<SensitiveDataReadable> actualResponse,  List <SensitiveDataReadable> expectedResponse,  string[] filterParams)

{

  if (filterParams.contains("sensitiveData"))
  {
    if(actualResponse !=null)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < expectedResponse.Count; i++)
        {
           if((actualResponse[i].Key !=null)
                      {
                actualResponse[i].Key.Value.ToString().Should.BeEquivalentTo(expectedResponse[i].Key.Value.ToString());
              }
        }
        return;
    }
    else
    {
       actualResponse.Should().BeNull();
    }
  }

}
```

Is it possible for me to reduce the duplicate code by adding method#2 parameters in method#1 and eliminating method #2?

OR

By calling method #1 from the method #2 by converting the datatype?

Comment: The title is not for tags. That's what tags are for. I've fixed that. Can you please fix the code formatting yourself?

Comment: Can you not use C# generics here - `Protected void ValidateSensitiveDataValues(List < T > actualResponse, List < T > expectedResponse, string[] filterParams)`?!

Comment: Thanks both of you for your quick response. I'm a beginner in C# programming.   As a tester, I had the script wrote to test the API response call, which gives Data and Sensitive Data key values pair separately in json. Above two methods are working for me individually for test cases but I want to club them and reduce any one duplicate code method. @Nitika - I checked for C# generics and the dev member are using it in service.cs class.  I'm not sure if I can use this above for test validation method or not.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the full step definitions as well as the "duplicated code". Since this is tagged [tag:specflow], can you include the steps from the feature file?

Answer (score 0):

A typical approach would be to use generics, this lets you define a method that can take any type, or some subset of types as parameters:

```
public bool ValidateSensitiveDataValues<T>(IEnumerable<T> actual, IEnumerable<T> expected, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer){
    return actual.SequenceEqual(expected, comparer);
}
```

Note that if T is a class you either need to give the method a EqualityComparer-object, or restrict the method to only work if `T` implements IEquatable:  `ValidateSensitiveDataValues<T>(IEnumerable<T> actual, IEnumerable<T> expected) where T : IEquatable<T>`. I tend to prefer the former since it is more flexible. If you do not do this any reference objects will use reference equality, and that is probably not what you want.

You might also want to use a unit test library. NUnit is a poppular one that has Assert-methods like `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` and `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent`. Where only the former care about ordering of the items.